# Proper Syntax for revZipAddUncompressedItemWithFile?

Tags: livecode

I recently found an error in the documentation for revZipAddItemWithData. Now I'm trying to do something similar, but this time using revZipAddUncompressedItemWithFile. I suspect I have a similar problem. I've tried every combination of quotes or no quotes around the arguments, with no luck. 
I'm not having trouble with any other handlers reading or writing to the zip archive, just this one.
Any ideas?

```
command SaveIssue
    put field "Archive Path" into tPath
    ask file "Save as:" with "someimage.jpg"
    put it into tFilePath
    set itemDelimiter to slash
    put item -1 of tFilePath into tFileName
    revZipOpenArchive tPath, "update"
    revZipAddUncompressedItemWithFile tPath, tFileName, "tFilePath"
    revZipCloseArchive tPath
end SaveIssue
```

Using LiveCode 6.6.2 stable, Mac OSX 10.9.4

Comment: What are the actual paths? The problem may be in the path (and hence permissions) instead of the arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get it working with no quotes around the arguments;

```
revZipAddUncompressedItemWithFile tPath, tFileName, tFilePath
```

However, it doesn't work with an archive that I create by right-clicking a file (on a Mac) and selecting 'Compress ...'  (The archive is reported as 'damaged' if I try to open it afterwards!)

It does work with an archive created with LiveCode

Comment: Also, I forgot to add revZipCloseArchive to the code on my actual working files, so the change to the archive wasn't taking effect.

Comment: I'm only using archives created by my application, so it doesn't affect me, but I read something about the encoding that revZip used being different from the "usual" encoding for zip files.